# How to define generic type for a function that takes in any Static Model and returns instances of that Model in with Sequelize

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, typescript-generics

I'm defining a function called `FieldSearch` that has the following parameters:

```js
fieldSearch<SpecificModel extends Model>(
  model: ModelStatic<SpecificModel>,

  // Having trouble with this
  fields: Array< attributes of the static model provided above >, 
  search: string // a query parameter used to search the fields
): Array<SpecificModel>
```

Since there's not one generic model and different models have different attributes, I'm not sure how I would go about generically typing the function to do the proper validation.

My User model, as an example, looks like the following:

```js
import {
  CreationOptional,
  DataTypes,
  InferAttributes,
  InferCreationAttributes,
  Model,
} from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from '../sequelize';

export default class User extends Model<
  InferAttributes<User, {}>,
  InferCreationAttributes<User, {}>
> {
  // id can be undefined during creation when using `autoIncrement`
  declare id: CreationOptional<number>;
  declare firstName: string;
  declare lastName: string;

  // createdAt can be undefined during creation
  declare createdAt: CreationOptional<Date>;
  // updatedAt can be undefined during creation
  declare updatedAt: CreationOptional<Date>;
  // deletedAt is only defined after the row is soft-deleted
  declare deletedAt: CreationOptional<Date>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an answer from looking at the [Sequelize types definition code](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/75563dbccf53b08f5c4a6261e8d24bd6b1a17f4c/src/model.d.ts)

```js
import { Model, ModelStatic } from 'sequelize';

// Every model must have an id so add that as a constraint on top of being a Model
interface StandardModel extends Model {
  id: number | string;
}

// Generic helper type that gets us the manually defined keys of the SpecificModel
type ModelStringAttributes<SpecificModel> = {
  // First filter only keys that are strings
  [Field in keyof SpecificModel]: SpecificModel[Field] extends string
    ? // Of the string field keys, if they are generic to the Model type ignore them
      Field extends keyof Model
      ? never
      : Field
    : never;
}[keyof SpecificModel];


// In our Generic typing, extend the StandardModel 
// so that we can guarantee a model with an id field
fieldSearch<SpecificModel extends StandardModel>(
  model: ModelStatic<SpecificModel>,

  // Fields should only contain keys that the Model has
  fields: ModelStringAttributes<SpecificModel>[],

  search: string // a query parameter used to search the fields
): SpecificModel[] // The function returns an array of whatever model was used
```